# Deriviation of terminal velocity with faulty results, under condition that $f=-cv^2$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics

*Note: There's a similar problem to this ([https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796694/how-to-derive-an-equation-for-terminal-velocity-assuming-air-resistance-is-some#:~:text=Taking%20proper%20sign%20of%20air,velocity%20as%20an%20asymptotic%20value.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796694/how-to-derive-an-equation-for-terminal-velocity-assuming-air-resistance-is-some#:%7E:text=Taking%20proper%20sign%20of%20air,velocity%20as%20an%20asymptotic%20value.)). However, I have a different approach and the above will not solve my problem.*

Consider the differential equation $$ma = -mg-cv^2$$
As stated in the above similar problem as well. What I did is differentiation (instead of solving directly). Considering initial conditions, I obtained
$$m\frac{da}{dt} = -2cva$$
$$\ln{a} = -2cvt/m+C_1$$
$$a = ge^{\frac{-2cvt}{m}}$$
Assuming $v=v_0$ at $t=0$, integration yields
$$v = -\frac{mg}{2cv}e^{\frac{-2cv}{m}t} + (v_0+\frac{mg}{2cv})$$
This suggests that the terminal velocity, which is obtained when $t=\inf$, is dependent on $v_0$, inconsistent with theory.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: In going from $\dfrac {da}{dt}=-2cva$ step to $\ln a=-2cvt+C1$ step, you have assumed the variable v to be constant, which it is not.

Comment: However, using $v=\dot x$ you get to $\ln(a)=2cx+C$, which can lead to a solution, but on a very convoluted route. // This could be circumvented, the terminal velocity is a stationary point, thus a root of the right side $0=-mg-c|v|v$, giving $v<0$ and $v_\infty=-\sqrt{\frac{mg}{c}}$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I acknowledge that. I wonder if anything may go wrong by differentiating in the first step, due to the fact that it makes the $-mg$ term disappear.

Comment: @Cyh1368 I’m not really qualified in physics, so the most I can say is that the constant in such DEs usually changes the initial value: take the example of an SHM: The time period of oscillation of a spring-mass system (spring attached to a wall/ceiling) is same, regardless of whether it is on a horizontal surface (no effect of mg) or is hanging in a vertical plane (effect of mg: changes the length of spring wrt the mean position from 0 to mg/k)

Comment: That’s a clear analogy, thanks.

Comment: Another error is that if you differentiate the first equation, you get $m\frac{da}{dt} = -2cva$. You dropped the $m$ on this and the next equation, though it does make an appropriately placed appearance on the equation after that, so apparently it was poor copying? In any case, differentiating loses information, in the form of an additive constant (the anti-derivative is unique, up to a constant). You can obtain that constant from the original equation, which apparently you did by assuming $v_0 = 0$ (thus giving you $g$ as the coefficient of the exponentiation).

Answer (score 1):

This differential equation does not have a terminal velocity, the acceleration is always greater than $g$ in downward direction, thus the velocity in that direction always increasing.

Obviously this is not physical. For the physical equation the friction force has to be in the opposite direction to the velocity, so
$$
ma = -mg - c|v|v=-mg-cv^2\hat v
$$
where in the one-dimensional case the direction unit vector is $\hat v=sign(v)$.